# Rails Elastic Search reindex data after update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am using Searchkick for interacting with elastic search api in my Rails app, and it's working fine almost for all the cases, but the problem I am facing is I am having status field in my Model, and through select all check box a User can change the status of all the records, so I am updating my data using `update_all` which doesn't fire any callback, and searchkick reindex data through `after_commit` callback. and since, my data is not getting `reindexed` in Elastic Search this way it's giving same results, what I am suppose to do, is calling `Model.reindex` manually is a good option??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually solved it, without re indexing whole data which would have been a really naive solution, instead of that we can also re index a single record Like below

```
product = Product.find 10
product.reindex
# or to reindex in the background
product.reindex_async
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `Model.reindex` manually. `action_all` is build to make changes at DB level directly. Find more [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all).

You can create `after_action` filter to reindex data.

Comment: It's okk to do it at local i tried it, but won't it create a problem on production we are having 50k+ records on production, reindexing 50k records may take decent time??

Comment: Yes it will take time you can call this reindex in background also. Create background job for reindex only. And call it in `afetr_action`.

Comment: You can do it like this also `models.find_each { |m| m.update_attributes(params) }` It will take more time though. Because update and reindex will call number of record times.